# List all the files which do not contain a particular string

Tags: shell, scripting

I would like to know which files do not include a particular header file in C.

For example:

#### file1.c

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "my.h"
```

...

#### file2.c

```
#include "stdio.h"
```

....

I would like to find out similar files (like file2.c) which do not contain `#include "my.h"`.

Comment: Note that you should be writing `#include <stdio.h>` because that's what the C standard uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
shopt -s nullglob
for file in *.c
do
   if grep -q "my.h" "$file" ;then
     continue
   else
      echo "found file that don't have my.h"
   fi
done
```

Or  you could use:

```
grep -L "my.h" *.c
```

if you have nothing else to process except to echo out file names. :)

Answer (score 3):

On Unix systems:

```
grep -L '#include.*my\.h' *.c
```

Comment: This lists files which contain at least one line which doesn't match the regex.